# Version of Root File System in Linux

Tags: linux

How do I identify the version of the Root File System that is currently being run in my machine?

Is there any particular file that contains this info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you are referring to. Could you give an example? Are you referring to the filesystem? or the FHS?

Comment: What is the "version of the Root File System"?

Comment: Do you mean the file system type of the root file system? Do you want to know if it's ext4, xfs or something else? Maybe just running `mount` could help you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as version of root file system.

If you meant type of file root system, you can get it with:

```
mount -v | grep " on / "
```

This might print something like:

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
```

Now, you can get more deep info about root fs using tune2fs (but only for `ext2`, `ext3` or `ext4`):

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2
```

It will print a lot of into about filesystem, and that will include mount count, which is likely what you meant.